# How do I use /etc/named.conf to configure named on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, named-conf

I've been reading a bit on how to configure my own DNS server. I have a host of questions but this is the first that came up:

1. I edited `/etc/named.conf` and created the appropriate zone files.
2. I tried to restart bind9 with a `service bind9 restart`.
3. A quick grep of syslog shows that it's not running with the changes I specified in `/etc/named.conf`.

**How do I get `/etc/named.conf` to be loaded?**

(I gave up after a while and after looking at the output from `named-checkconf -p`, I started editing files in `/var/cache/bind` as well as `/etc/bind/`)

Comment: Are there any configuration files in `/etc/named/`?

Comment: There's no such directory. So the answer is no. I /did/ create a directory called `/var/named/` as root and then referenced that path in the options of the named.conf file, but that didn't help.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use /etc/bind on ubuntu?..

Comment: Maybe you installed named with chroot and configs are in /var/named/chroot/etc

Comment: @pauska Quite possibly but where's the documentation for that? That's the frustrating part because I do a `man named` and there's nothing there about using `/etc/bind`.

Comment: @AveryChan https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto

Comment: @pauska Thanks! Sigh. I needed this two hours ago. :)

Comment: Are there any interesting error messages in your logs (/var/log/syslog). Is there anything interesting in the output of  /usr/sbin/named -g ?

Comment: @AveryChan, When you installed bind, you didn't install a packaged called named did you, you installed a packaged called bind.  So the obvious first choice to look for package configs would be `/etc/{packagename}`.  You could also run a command like this.  `dpkg --listfiles bind9 | grep /etc`.  You could have also done something like `find /etc -name '*named.conf*'`.

Comment: @Zoredache bind was part of the default install. The `dpkg` command didn't display anything, but the `find` command was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `service bind9 restart` should work. For bind9 on Ubuntu v11.10, the default location for named.conf is `/etc/bind/named.conf` not `/etc/named.conf`.

In general, the init script (`/etc/init.d/bind9`) should point you to where the configuration file resides.

For bind9 on Ubuntu v11.10, there is a bind settings file at `/etc/default/bind9` but it is only used to set command line options when starting named - which shouldn't matter, unless someone edited this file to add an argument to redirect where named.conf resides.

NOTE: I wouldn't move the configuration file away from its default location without good reason nor would I edit what is in `/var/named` directly (isn't this autocreated).

Another thing to check is: have you tried `service bind9 stop` and then confirmed that named is no longer running and then started (with `service bind9 start`) it again?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I have noticed that the named man page is completely wrong on ubuntu 10.04 about the config file. It seems to actually be /etc/bind/named.conf rather than what the man page states (/etc/named.conf). I figured this out by reading the system log when bind9 starts and noticing that it was built with sysconfdir=/etc/bind

I hope someone notices the error and fixes in at some point.